# printing the ampersand

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that takes a url with variables and writes it to a file, problem is the ampersand is interfering and being interpreted as a command / control character.

In this situation the string cannot be escaped BEFORE being passed to the script and I have yet to find any way to do this.

```
if [ $1 ] ; then
    url=$1
    printf %q "$url" > "/somepath/somefile"
fi
```

with $1 being for example localhost?x=1&y=2&z=3

What get's printed is only the part before the first ampersand: "localhost?x=1"

I have also tried echo instead of printf but it's exactly the same ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is fine, but you need to invoke the script with a quoted parameter:

```
./myscript.sh "localhost?x=1&y=2&z=3"
```

Comment: Thanks, all your suggestions have solved this, needed to quote the parameters and then all works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with echo nor print. The problem is that when you run the script, it starts those 2 jobs in background. For more information you can check: http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand.
You can simply start script with 'localhost?x=1&y=2&z=3' in apostrophes, so bash will not treat ampersand as operator but just as normal character.

Answer (score 0):

Quote things. Replace all `$1`s with `"$1"`s. And quote argument when you actually invoke your script.